# updating value in info.plist programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, plist, info.plist

I have a value inside of my info.plist called radiusDistance that i'm trying to change, i've attempted using this code but it doesn't change the value

```
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Info", ofType: "plist")!
    var dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) as! [String: AnyObject]


    let radiusDistance = dict["radiusDistance"]
    print("radiusDistance",radiusDistance as Any)
    let value = Int(5)


    do{
         dict.updateValue(value as AnyObject, forKey: "radiusDistance")
     try path.write(toFile: path, atomically: false, encoding:String.Encoding.utf8)
    }
    catch let error as NSError{
        print("something went horribly wrong\(error.debugDescription)")
    }
```

Everything runs but when I go back to my info.plist nothing changes, and the value remains at "0"

Comment: You should load your plist the first time your app launches and save it somewhere locally. After that you can do whatever you want to your property list file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An app's bundle is read-only. You can't save changes to your bundle.

### EDIT:

And, as "Alexander" says, you should not try to make a program self-modifying. That's bad coding practice, even if it was possible.

Comment: The more importantly: not only can you not, but you also *shouldn't*, even if it were possible.

Comment: Alright thank you for the help, I had not known this before